# Will perfectly parallel light beams lose intensity when passing through a long black tunnel due to diffraction?

Tags: optics

If I took a long light-absorbing tunnel with a small opening which absorbed all light that hit the side of the tunnel and shined a laser down it, would the light appear very dimmed at the end of the tunnel due to light continuously diffracting throughout the tunnel?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the tunnel is larger than the beam at least at its entry, and the tunnel axis is well aligned with the beam axis. If the tunnel length is comparable to or longer than the [Rayleigh length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_length), yes, the beam will touch the walls and part of it will be absorbed. Otherwise no, it can pass almost undisturbed. To model the adsorption you need to compare the (assumed) gaussian beam profile radius  with the radius of the tunnel.

Comment: But doesn't diffraction play a role in this?

Comment: @Goldname, diffraction is what determines the Rayleigh length and the beam radius.